# How to fetch columns in reverse order with PHPCassa

Tags: cassandra, phpcassa

How to fetch the columns in a single row in reverse order with PHPCassa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trick is done with empty column slice object.

```
...

$cf = new ColumnFamily($pool, 'mycolumnfamily');

// normal order
$rows = $cf->get('mykey'); 

print_r($rows);

// reverse order, 5 is column count, true is reverse order
$rows = $cf->get('mykey', new ColumnSlice(null, null, 5, true) );

print_r($rows);
```

Answer (score 3):

From phpcassa documentation

```
 public function get($key,
                     $columns=null,
                     $column_start="",
                     $column_finish="",
                     $column_reversed=False,
                     $column_count=self::DEFAULT_COLUMN_COUNT,
                     $super_column=null,
                     $read_consistency_level=null)
```

See **"@param `bool $column_reversed` fetch the columns in reverse order"**

Setting this parameter to "true" will fetch the columns in reverse order.

You can even set this parameter for **multiget, get_range and get_indexed_slices** queries.

For More Detail see: [phpcassa columnfamily documentation](http://api.efine.cz/phpcassa/class-ColumnFamily.html)

Comment: The docs you linked to seem to be for an old version (basically 0.8.a.2).  The most recent version can be found here: http://thobbs.github.com/phpcassa/api/class-phpcassa.ColumnFamily.html#_get